# Bind data using Repeater in c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I need to bind some data on view page and the data will fetch from database using c# asp.net.I tried to implement Repeater but i can not know how to bind multiple data inside it.the following is my original view file.

> index.aspx:

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper text-justify">  
                                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMissionId"  >
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                    <img src="pic/our-phylosophy.jpg" width="260" height="246" alt="" class="alignleft"> 
                                    <h1>
                                    <b>Heading</b>
                                    </h1>
                                    <p>
                                    description
                                    </p>
                                    <br/>
                                    <h1>
                                    <b>Heading</b>
                                    </h1>
                                    <p>
                                    description
                                    </p><br> 
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </div>
```

In the above section one image is present and two set of data also there.Here i need to fetch image from database and set here in image place similarly heading and description in their proper place.My requirement is the last row of table image will set here and the heading,description of last two row will set here.

I am using 3-tire architecture here so please check my below code.

> index.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            indexBL objMissionBl = new indexBL();
            rptMissionId.DataSource = objMissionBl.getMissionData();
            rptMissionId.DataBind();
        }
```

> indexBL.cs:

```
private indexDL objMissionDL = new indexDL();
        public DataSet getMissionData()
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = objMissionDL.getMissionData();
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

> IndexDL.cs:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CmVar.convar);
        public DataSet getMissionData()
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM T_Mission_Vission WHERE Heading='Mission' ORDER BY Mission_vision_ID DESC";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                SqlDataAdapter objadp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                objadp.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

I explained my requirement,if something is wrong or need to add please change it and help me to resolve this.Thanks.

Comment: I can see you are only fetching 1 record from DB then why you need a Repeater control?

Comment: @ Rahul : Actually i am totally new to ASP.NET.Can you please edit this code for getting the proper output.For one record which controller is useful to bind data.

Comment: You need a simple mark-up with server side controls, You can then assign their values in code behind. Please refer to some good tutorial if you are new to ASP.NET

Comment: @ Rahul : You mean for image i have to bind data inside image controller and for description label controller and so on..?